# Odd Memory behavior

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management

I basically have an object, which I call two functions from, and three functions.

```
function func1()
    M.mfunc1( 'updateSomething' );
    // do some stuff
    M.mfunc2();
}

function func2 () {
  M.mfunc1 ( 'hitSomething' );
  // does something but line is stable
  M.mfunc2();
}

function func3 () {
  M.mfunc1 ( 'doesSoemthing' );
  //does nothing, but causes memory to grow
  M.mfunc2();
}

M.mfunc1 = function ( name ) {
  // code is all commented out
}

M.mfunc2 = function () {
  // code is all commented out
}
```

`func1`n is called on a main loop using setTimeout. When using Chromes's Dev Tools on the Timeline watching Memory, memory suddenly grows on the call of `func3`, but if I comment out the `M` calls, it stays stable. I resorted to commenting everything out of `M.mfunc1` and `M.mfunc2` and by just calling it a lone, it causes memory usage to grow.

Now can someone explain that to me?

**Update**: I made my code more like what it really is.

**Update 2**: Since the example code I gave doesn't seem to be the problem, here's a link to all the code: http://test.startailpro.co.uk/breaking/

The functions are `update`, `updateDirection`, `hitBlock`, `doesBall_hitBlock`, `MEMORY.deep` and `MEMORY.rise`.

Comment: So the call to func3 from func1 doesn't cause an issue? Only from func2?

Comment: I rather doubt we can help much without seeing real code that exhibits the issue.

Comment: @ThatMatthew yeap, doesn't cause an issue at all

Comment: @jfriend00 made the code look like what it is in reality.

Comment: How much does memory usage grow by each time you call the function?

Comment: It's continuous growth. So much so GC kicks in, which for a game is not good.

Comment: I think @jfriend00 was asking how much it grows on each iteration

Comment: It's not easy to determine that, but about 200KB every second.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, there is a built in heap-snapshot tool under the 'Profiles' section.  Breakpoint before one iteration, take snapshot.  Let it run for one iteration, take snapshot.  It'll show you a delta on memory and instance counts on items such as strings.

Comment: Well, with Matt's advice it grows 60Bs in array, 24B in Object and 12B in numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for that. All I need now is it to tell me where and who allocates the memory.

Comment: I think the fact that you see growth in Arrays, Objects, and numbers tells us your code above is an incomplete example, since no-where in those code paths are there any allocations, and you seem to imply there could not be.  Which is obviously not happening.  Are you sure you're calling the functions you think you're calling?

Comment: To make life easier, I've given the link to all the code.

Comment: The funny thing is, I've been through this code hundreds of times and I can't see where arrays and objects are begin created because I trying to reuse them

Comment: Right, I have done it again, just to make sure and here's the new results 484B of arrays, 24B of Objects and 12B of numbers. The only interesting thing to add, if I didn't do quick enough, I would get a decrease rather than increase. So it's defiantly to do with the main loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I did was rewrite the whole code. I actually managed to write the whole thing without using objects, except on load. I still don't know what's wrong from the original code, but I am now better able to understand memory is used an grows.

[Memory being allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7349344/398640)

I would recommend being careful what framework you choose. I found in jQuery that events causes memory growth. Since your receiving an object and an object is being generated for the event this not be a issue. Although, I am under the assumption that event objects are native and have been optimised so memory growth is not an issue. Again, be careful of frameworks.