# Memory being allocated

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management

By using the Chrome Development Tools, I found out arrays and objects were being allocated. I gone through my code looking for the obvious `[]`, `{}` and`new`. But there isn't any. I have checked functions that create a new `[]`, `{}`, `new` and looked to see where those functions are used, and I've learnt not to use them. So, how else can memory be allocated?

This is a problem for me, because every time GC kicks in, it blocks the main loop and the animation becomes inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fruitless to worry overmuch about memory allocation. Memory will be allocated for everything, variables, arrays, objects, etc. There isn't much you could do with javascript without using a variable or an object, but again, the allocation of memory is not really the domain of a javascript **script**. Any and all javascript will use some degree of memory no matter what. Indeed, I would say that if you have "learned to avoid using" objects and arrays, you have been misinformed or are learning the wrong lesson.

It is far more important to avoid circular references, to avoid excessive memory consumption *per scope*, and to generally avoid locking up the browser thread with tight loops and other bad practices. For instance, in a `for` loop, avoid recalculating the limit in the `for` declaration:  `for (var x = 1; x < myString.length; x++)` should be `var max = myString.length; for(var x = 1; x < max; x++)`. Even such optimizations (*micro*-optimizations in most cases) are not **critical** to a javascript developer, for the browser is handling the overall memory allocation/consumption as well as the garbage collection of out-of-scope references.

For more information about practical practices to avoid **leaks**, check out this article: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index.shtml (or other articles like this). Otherwise, as long as you aren't *leaking* memory, it is expected that any script will allocate/use some degree of memory; it is unavoidable. Considering that the modern PC has *gigabytes* of memory available, your script's paltry *kilobytes* or even *megabytes* of memory use are not of much consequence - that's what the memory is there for, to use it.

Comment: My problem is that GC kicks in, destroying a perfectly smooth game. But it it good to know how memory is actually being allocated. Thanks

Comment: GC varies from browser to browser, and should be totally opaque to a script. Indeed, there is no way to manually fire or otherwise interact with the GC from javascript - the GC exists as something javascript doesn't even "know" about. Most browsers run the GC when it is convenient to do so, when there is no or low demand on the browser for front-end activities (like executing your script). If there are odd performance issues, look to your code, not to the GC.

Comment: Are you saying that, because of the main loop GC cannot work accordingly and so memory piles up until it has no choice but to kick in?

Comment: If you are forcing a never-ending, recursive loop, then yes, the browser **may** delay GC until it becomes critically necessary. Rather than a constant loop, it might be better to give some breathing space with `setTimeout`. Timeouts are not as rigid as directly recursive functions or loops, the browser is allowed to delay firing of a timeout if it is busy with something else (like GC), whereas a never-ending for loop would not be as lightly interrupted. Keep in mind, the GC should only take miliseconds to do what it needs to do.

Comment: Using `setTimout` I get the same effect. The loop is a function, `setTimout` calls that function, but memory still grows and then GC kicks in. But from what you said this is natural, since practically everything is allocated to memory. All I'm trying to do is give time to the GC to take a few milliseconds and clean things up, or reduce the amount of allocations.

Comment: You're best served by keeping your memory footprint as low as possible, using setTimeout does not guarantee that the GC will use the space you gave it. GC is, from the perspective of javascript, mysterious voodoo that happens at the whim of the spirit-gods. Plus, your experiences and tweakings in Chrome won't apply in Firefox or IE, since their GC is going to behave differently. If you notice memory consumption spiking, you really should be looking for leaky closures or circular references to elements that are removed from DOM, that kind of thing. Simple use is not the culprit, leaks are.